# Car won't start, only 3 years old

Tags: battery, starting, dodge, battery-drain, jump-start

My '16 Dart SXT for the past month won't start without needing a jump if it sits for a day without being used. Starter is fine, thought it was the battery so bought a new one and less then a week later it started needing to be jumped again, checked the alternator with volt meter and it's good. I have no idea what else to check or what it could be without spending money to take it to the dealer or a mechanic.

Comment: Sounds like there's a load draining the battery... might want to try running a voltmeter on the battery (with car off) and removing relays 1 by 1 to see if anything causes a change in voltage.